# Interdependencies between subfig, subfigure and subcaption for journal papers

Tags: floats, subfloats, document-classes

I am using [informs3.cls](https://www.informs.org/Find-Research-Publications/INFORMS-Journals/Author-Portal/LaTeX-Style-Files) template to write a paper. I have run into serious difficulty when making a figure with subfigures. The problem is that:

- `subfigure` package is obsolete.
- `subfig` is not compatible with `hyperref`.
- `subcaption` conflicts with `informs3` template.

This is what I have gathered from other questions on this topic on the net. Every combination I tried among these packages throws up some error or the other because of such dependencies. How should I get a subfigure done for INFORMS paper in this case?

Comment: Did you think of giving a try at `floatrow` ? It has a `subfloatrow` environment.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to `informs3.cls`?

Comment: Have you asked the people at INFORMS? Since you are writing an artivcle for one of their journals, they surely can give you the best alternative to conform to their style and guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

I tried an example I had with the `informs3` class using `subfig`, to which I added also `hyperref`.

There is no real incompatibility of `subfig` with `hyperref`, actually: the cross references are made into links as expected; the anchor may not be optimal, but the links work.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Author template for Organization Science (orsc)
%% Mirko Janc, Ph.D., INFORMS, mirko.janc@informs.org
%% ver. 0.95, December 2010
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\documentclass[orsc,blindrev]{informs3}
\documentclass[orsc,nonblindrev]{informs3} % current default for manuscript submission

\DoubleSpacedXI % Made default on 4/4/2014 per request
%%\OneAndAHalfSpacedXI % current default line spacing
%%\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII
%%\DoubleSpacedXII

% If hyperref is used, dvi-to-ps driver of choice must be declared as
%   an additional option to the \documentclass. For example
%\documentclass[dvips,orsc]{informs3}      % if dvips is used
%\documentclass[dvipsone,orsc]{informs3}   % if dvipsone is used, etc.

%%% ORSC uses endnotes!
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\let\enotesize=\normalsize
\def\notesname{Endnotes}%
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip0pt\leftskip0pt\parindent=0em
  \leavevmode\hbox{\makeenmark}}

% Private macros here (check that there is no clash with the style)
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

% Natbib setup for author-year style
\usepackage{natbib}
 \bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{,}{a}{}{,}%
 \def\bibfont{\small}%
 \def\bibsep{\smallskipamount}%
 \def\bibhang{24pt}%
 \def\newblock{\ }%
 \def\BIBand{and}%

\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Setup of theorem styles. Outcomment only one. 
%% Preferred default is the first option.
\TheoremsNumberedThrough     % Preferred (Theorem 1, Lemma 1, Theorem 2)
%\TheoremsNumberedByChapter  % (Theorem 1.1, Lema 1.1, Theorem 1.2)

%% Setup of the equation numbering system. Outcomment only one.
%% Preferred default is the first option.
\EquationsNumberedThrough    % Default: (1), (2), ...
%\EquationsNumberedBySection % (1.1), (1.2), ...

% In the reviewing and copyediting stage enter the manuscript number.
%\MANUSCRIPTNO{} % When the article is logged in and DOI assigned to it,
                 %   this manuscript number is no longer necessary

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Outcomment only when entries are known. Otherwise leave as is and 
%   default values will be used.
%\setcounter{page}{1}
%\VOLUME{00}%
%\NO{0}%
%\MONTH{Xxxxx}% (month or a similar seasonal id)
%\YEAR{0000}% e.g., 2005
%\FIRSTPAGE{000}%
%\LASTPAGE{000}%
%\SHORTYEAR{00}% shortened year (two-digit)
%\ISSUE{0000} %
%\LONGFIRSTPAGE{0001} %
%\DOI{10.1287/xxxx.0000.0000}%

% Author's names for the running heads
% Sample depending on the number of authors;
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones}
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones and Wilson}
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones, Miller, and Wilson}
% \RUNAUTHOR{Jones et al.} % for four or more authors
% Enter authors following the given pattern:
%\RUNAUTHOR{}

% Title or shortened title suitable for running heads. Sample:
% \RUNTITLE{Bundling Information Goods of Decreasing Value}
% Enter the (shortened) title:
%\RUNTITLE{}

% Full title. Sample:
\TITLE{Bundling Information Goods of Decreasing Value}
% Enter the full title:
%\TITLE{}

% Block of authors and their affiliations starts here:
% NOTE: Authors with same affiliation, if the order of authors allows, 
%   should be entered in ONE field, separated by a comma. 
%   \EMAIL field can be repeated if more than one author
\ARTICLEAUTHORS{%
\AUTHOR{Author1}
\AFF{Author1 affiliation, \EMAIL{}, \URL{}}
\AUTHOR{Author2}
\AFF{Author2 affiliation, \EMAIL{}, \URL{}}
% Enter all authors
} % end of the block

\ABSTRACT{%
Text of your abstract % Enter your abstract
}%

% Sample
%\KEYWORDS{deterministic inventory theory; infinite linear programming duality; 
%  existence of optimal policies; semi-Markov decision process; cyclic schedule}

% Fill in data. If unknown, outcomment the field
\KEYWORDS{}

\maketitle
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Samples of sectioning (and labeling) in ORSC
% NOTE: (1) \section and \subsection do NOT end with a period
%       (2) \subsubsection and lower need end punctuation
%       (3) capitalization is as shown (title style).
%
%\section{Introduction.}\label{intro} %%1.
%\subsection{Duality and the Classical EOQ Problem.}\label{class-EOQ} %% 1.1.
%\subsection{Outline.}\label{outline1} %% 1.2.
%\subsubsection{Cyclic Schedules for the General Deterministic SMDP.}
%  \label{cyclic-schedules} %% 1.2.1
%\section{Problem Description.}\label{problemdescription} %% 2.

% Text of your paper here

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
mollit anim id est laborum.\endnote{Lex I: Corpus omne perseverare 
in statu suo quiescendi vel movendi uniformiter in directum, nisi quatenus a viribus 
impressis cogitur statum illum mutare (excerpit de {\it Philosophi\ae\ Naturalis Principia Mathematica}).}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subfloat[$\rho^2-\theta_1$ and $\rho^2-\theta_2$]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
}%
\subfloat[$\delta_1-\theta_1$ and $\delta_1-\theta_2$]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-b}%
}

\subfloat[The variation of $\theta_1$ with $\rho^2$ and $\delta_1$]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image-c}%
}%
\subfloat[The variation of $\theta_2$ with $\rho^2$ and $\delta_1$]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{example-image}%
  \label{subfigure}%
}

\medskip
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
\small
 (a) evaluated at $(\delta_0, \delta_1)=(0.1,0.01)$ and $(\alpha,\beta)=(1,1)$, \\
 (b) evaluated at $(\delta_0,\rho^2)=(0.1,1)$ and $(\alpha,\beta)=(1,1)$, \\
 and (c) (d) evaluated at $\delta_0=0.1$ and $(\alpha,\beta)=(1,1)$.
\end{minipage}

\medskip

\caption{The variation of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ with respect to $\rho^2$and $\delta_1$}
\label{figure}

\end{figure}

Now we cite the subfigure~\ref{subfigure} in figure~\ref{figure}

\clearpage

Now we cite the subfigure~\ref{subfigure} in figure~\ref{figure}



% Acknowledgments here
\ACKNOWLEDGMENT{%
% Enter the text of acknowledgments here
}% Leave this (end of acknowledgment)


% Appendix here
% Options are (1) APPENDIX (with or without general title) or 
%             (2) APPENDICES (if it has more than one unrelated sections)
% Outcomment the appropriate case if necessary
%
% \begin{APPENDIX}{<Title of the Appendix>}
% \end{APPENDIX}
%
%   or 
%
% \begin{APPENDICES}
% \section{<Title of Section A>}
% \section{<Title of Section B>}
% etc
% \end{APPENDICES}

\bigskip

% Endnotes here
\theendnotes

\bigskip

% References here (outcomment the appropriate case) 

% CASE 1: BiBTeX used to constantly update the references 
%   (while the paper is being written).
%\bibliographystyle{ormsv080} % outcomment this and next line in Case 1
%\bibliography{<your bib file(s)>} % if more than one, comma separated

% CASE 2: BiBTeX used to generate mypaper.bbl (to be further fine tuned)
%\input{mypaper.bbl} % outcomment this line in Case 2

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but I recently had this issue. I put each plot into a subfigure environment, put all of these subfigures into a minipage, and then gave the minipage as the argument to \FIGURE.

If you are dealing with multiple subtables you can do the same thing with \TABLE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `:)` You might consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the solution you describe.